# How to retain decimal places when coercing numeric data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe in R like the following:

```
score<-c("2.5","3","2","2.5","3")
df<-data.frame(score)
```

I want the data from this column to be read as numeric.

However, when I use `as.numeric`, I receive the following results:

```
as.numeric(df$score)
[1] 2 3 2 2 3
```

How can I coerce this data into a numeric class while also retaining the decimal places?

In my real data set, R initially reads in this column as a factor. I'm familiar with the solutions from [R-FAQ 7.10](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f), and I convert my data to character first (`as.numeric(as.character(df$score)`), but I still can't retain the decimal places using `as.numeric()`.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Check `getOption*"digits")`. If it's 0 or 1, then the numbers are correct but just not being *printed* that way. Set with `options(digits=3)` (something 2 or higher for this usage) and try again, you should see `[1] 2.5 3.0 2.0 2.5 3.0`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. The code gives a dataframe with a numeric score column with decimals. Also, do you have a typo? as.dataframe?

Comment: `as.dataframe()` is not a function in base R, so I don't know what you're doing.   If you do `as.numeric(score)` you can see that it works ... unless, as already noted, you have an odd setting for `options(digits)`.

Comment: If there is any doubt ... that typo should have been `getOption("digits")`

Comment: Thanks to zx8754 and dank for pointing out my typo when defining my dataframe in my example. I've corrected this.

Comment: r2evan's suggestion worked. Thank you!